# Matplotlib bar chart from dataframe ValueError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm trying to make a simple bar chart from a data frame. My data frame looks like this:

```
    start_date     AvgPrice
0    2018-03-17  3146.278673
1    2018-12-08  3146.625048
2    2018-11-10  3148.762809
3    2018-11-17  3151.926036
4    2018-11-03  3153.965413
5    2018-02-03  3155.831255
6    2018-11-24  3161.057180
7    2018-01-27  3162.143680
8    2018-03-10  3162.239096
9    2018-01-20  3166.450869
..          ...          ...
337  2018-07-13  8786.797679
338  2018-07-20  8969.859386
```

My code basically looks like this:

```
x = df.start_date
x = x.to_string() #convert datetime objects to strings
y = df.AvgPrice

# Plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(x, y, width=30)

fig.savefig('week price bar chart')

plt.close(fig)
```

However I get the following error:

```
File "PriceHistogram.py", line 68, in plot
ax.bar(x, y, width=30)
File "/home/rune/env3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1898, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/rune/env3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 2079, in bar
    "must be length %d or scalar" % nbars)
ValueError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 6101 or scalar
```

Comment: Basically, the error message says your `height` (which is `y`) doesn't match your `left` (which is `x`). Your `left` seems to have 6101 elements while your `height` doesn't have exactly 6101 elements. Besides, your sample code seems strange. Your `x` was converted to `str`. Then your `ax.bar()` should fail since `left` suppose to be "sequence of scalars".

Comment: Thanks. That does make much sense to me though as the data frame has 338 rows. I'm converting x to str as I don't want the x-values ordered by date. I want to treat them as strings (the data frame is ordered by the y-values). Do you have a suggestion for how the plot the data frame as a bar chart with matplotlib?

Comment: You can try to modify the [example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) and see if that can give you what you want. I give an example below. But honestly, I don't know whether that's what you want or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure if this is what you want. It was modified from the [example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) in matplotlib's documentation.

```
import io

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = """start_date AvgPrice
2018-03-17 3146.278673
2018-12-08 3146.625048
2018-11-10 3148.762809
2018-11-17 3151.926036
2018-11-03 3153.965413
2018-02-03 3155.831255
2018-11-24 3161.057180
2018-01-27 3162.143680
2018-03-10 3162.239096
2018-01-20 3166.450869"""

df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(s), sep=' ', header=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
width = 0.8
b = ax.bar(np.arange(len(df.AvgPrice)), df.AvgPrice, width=width)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(df.AvgPrice)) + width / 2)
ax.set_xticklabels(df.start_date, rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]